# gsutil no urls matched, yet appears in cloud storage browser

Tags: google-cloud-storage, missing-data, gsutil

I'm attempting to retrieve a database backup we've put into Cloud Storage. To make a long story short, the url is gs://servername/year/date/data.sql

It's a little more complicated than that, but for the sake of this question, it'll do.

Anyway, when I use the Storage Browser (Projects -> Storage -> Storage Browser), I can get into /server/2014/2014-09/04/ - but this is where things get weird.

The subfolders/directories phase in and out of existence, *only* for this date. I can go in and out of the bucket subfolder of 2014-09-04 all day, and it'll have different results every time. Sometimes the incremental data is there, sometimes only the schema data is there. Trying to download any file from the storage browser gives a big fat "Not Found" blank error page. No links, no http response codes. Just, "Not Found". All our older dated folders are fine.

If I use gsutil to attempt to retrieve the entire subfolder, it says:

**CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://servername/2014/2014-09-04**

The command I ran was:

**gsutil.py mv gs://server/2014/2014-09-04 c:\dbrestore\**

Yet there it is in the storage browser, clear as day. (There is only one ACL, so I know that's not the problem) To make sure I wasn't doing something funky, I have copied dates surrounding it ok, so 2014-09-03 and 2014-09-05 are both completely accessible from the storage browser, and gsutil.

I am out of ideas as to what could be wrong. Frankly, something about the bucket looks stuffed. Has anyone run into this problem before, and if so, what did you do to go about correcting it?

Comment: I presume "servername" was a purposefully generic name, not the real name. Can you please tell us the real name and exact commands you used. If you'd prefer not to post publicly you can email to gs-team@google.com.

Comment: Yes, I've intentionally obfuscated the name. I'll email you directly with the project-id and bucket name, thanks.

Comment: Is this question solved? If so, could you update it? Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this issue?  If the solution was provided, can you post a self-answer here to benefit the community or otherwise close this question?

Comment: Hi Lloyd - did you send the real name and exact commands used to gs-team@google.com? I don't see it there, so we'd appreciate if you could re-send. Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're running into a quirk I've brought up here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938367/890517 . Basically it's possible to have an object named `foo` and an object named `foo/` which is unlike most *nix filesystems.