# Is it possible to access directory from Google cloud storage without adding index.html?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to use Google Cloud Storage as a static website and the `index.html` object is stored in my bucket sub directory/folder, let's say `my-directory`

It is only accessible on this location `www.example.com/my-directory/index.html` but I want to access as `www.example.com/my-directory/` Is it possible?

I have tried to add MainPageSuffix as index.html but it's work only at root level.

Comment: Hey. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Nakilon NO I think it is not possible right now. So I am stick with firebase hosting.

Comment: You may want to star this ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67975966

Answer (score 2):

For future readers: It is possible, but due to a slight quirk hinted at [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) you may actually have an empty object named `my-directory/` *and* an object named `my-directory/index.html` so when you try and view it in your browser you are hitting the empty object that is not publicly accessible named `my-directory/`.

It's possible to determine if you have an empty object by using gsutil:

`gsutil ls -R gs://my-bucket/my-directory*`

You should see an output similar to this if you have an empty object:

```
gs://my-bucket/my-directory/:
gs://my-bucket/my-directory/           <- This is the empty object
gs://my-bucket/my-directory/index.html
```

To resolve this you can use gsutil to delete the empty object without affecting your other objects in the directory:

`gsutil rm gs://my-bucket/my-directory/`